# display area is increased

Tags: android, rendering, android-canvas, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have created surface in android Java and mentioned its width and height as below.

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

My decoded video dimension is `w x h` (less than surface layout size). When i render the yuv frames in native, video is filled complete area of the surface. I want to control the rendering area (it must be `w x h`). I tried with `native_window_set_buffers_geometry` and `native_window_set_crop` APIs. 
But still video is rendered will full area of surface.

I have used `NATIVE_WINDOW_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_WINDOW` option.